# eclipse C++ add reference undefined reference to method error

Tags: c++, eclipse, dll

I'm new to C++ and ecplice and they are definitely giving my a hard time :)
I'm tring to write simple application that includes main project with refernces to other project
i wrote the following file in shared project:

```
    
#ifndef MANAGEDLOG_H_
#define MANAGEDLOG_H_
#include string
#include iostream
#include fstream
    using namespace std;
 class ManagedLog 
{
 ofstream _fileStream;
public :
 ManagedLog::ManagedLog(string path);
 ManagedLog::~ManagedLog();
 void ManagedLog::WriteInfoLog(string message,string stackTrace);


};
#endif /* MANAGEDLOG_H_ */

/*
 * ManagedLog.cpp
 *
 *  Created on: 18/06/2010
 *      Author: Eran
 */
#include "ManagedLog.h"
#include iostream
#include fstream
ManagedLog::ManagedLog(string path)
{
 _path=path;
}
ManagedLog::~ManagedLog()
{
}
 void ManagedLog:: WriteInfoLog(string message,string stackTrace)
{
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open("Eample.txt",ios::app);
  myfile.close();


}
```

and run it in simple hellow world project:

```
    #include "ManagedLog.h"
#include 
using namespace std;

int main() {
 ManagedLog * log = new ManagedLog("path");
 log->WriteInfoLog("test","RunLog/Main");
 cout
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
*** Build of configuration Debug for project RunLog ****

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -ID:\EclipseWorkSpace\LogManager -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -osrc\RunLog.o ..\src\RunLog.cpp
g++ -LD:\EclipseWorkSpace\LogManager\Release -oRunLog.exe src\RunLog.o
src\RunLog.o: In function `main':
D:/EclipseWorkSpace/RunLog/Debug/../src/RunLog.cpp:13: undefined reference to `ManagedLog::ManagedLog(std::string)'
D:/EclipseWorkSpace/RunLog/Debug/../src/RunLog.cpp:14: undefined reference to `ManagedLog::WriteInfoLog(std::string, std::string)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Build error occurred, build is stopped
Time consumed: 574  ms.
```

I added #include "ManagedLog.cpp" and the code work just fine but i guess this is not the right way to do it  i read a lot about it but found no answer that i can impliment since i don't understad the term is the reanswers   can anybody please help me with the right way to point to other project or dll in this environment?
 thanks
Eran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not building `ManagedLog.cpp`.  Your compile sequence should look something like this example (simplified for clarity):

1. compile `RunLog.c` into `RunLog.o`
2. compile `ManagedLog.c` into `ManagedLog.o`
3. link `RunLog.o` and `ManagedLog.o` into `RunLog.exe`

Steps 1 & 2 could be in the other order if you like.

Comment: how can I link the .o files to the .exe?

Comment: @Eran, I have no idea - I have never used eclipse.  You want a command line that looks like `g++ src\RunLog.o src\ManagedLog.o -o RunLog.exe`.

Comment: OK!! I searched all over the RunLog Properties for linker property and found it in C/C++ Build-> Setting->ToolSettings ->MinGW C++ Linker ,I opend the Libararies folder and found a place to add object , i added the ManagedLog.o file and it worked like a magic
Thanks a lot for your tip I was just about quitting to c#  (-: